# api.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token not working

Tags: php, paypal

I wondered if I could request some assistance.  We had some code written by an external contractor to allow us to automatically set up billing agreements in paypal (client approves and future requests are automatically paid).

We have a sandbox environment making a call via **https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=**

This works fine.

In production this was changed to **https://api.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=**

This hangs.

I have updated the username, password and signature to production values, but we still have the same issue.

I also spent a lot of time reading through a lot of developer docs, but found them to be quite difficult to understand.

I also submitted a paypal "App" request for approval (this seemed to be required in the docs), and it has been approved.  However it says we should provide the production App ID when making a request, but there is no argument to do it.

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first URL you show looks like that would be the redirect to PayPal, not the actual API endpoint.

The endpoint URLs should be...

- Sandbox:  https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
- Live:  https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I'm a bit confused by that.  If this works fine: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=      do we need to change the "approach" for live.  I assumed we could just swap to the live URL and paypal handles everything neatly at its end?